# Openlayers import features to geoserver catalog

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

I have a simple feature collection returned from execution of the `vec:UnionFeatureCollection` WPS process. I need to import these features into the geoserver catalog, which basically means that I need to assign them a store and workspace. I have tried the `gs:Import` WPS process, which is as close as I have come but it fails without an exception. I am using Openlayers. Here is the code am using:

```
wpsClient1.execute({
    server:'local',
    process:'gs:Import',
    inputs:{
        features:featureCollection,
        coverage:'',
        workspace:'workspace1',
        store:'analysis',
        name:layerName,
        srs:new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326')
    },
    success:function(layerName1){
        localStorage.setItem("LayerName",JSON.stringify(layerName1));
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

I have also tried chaining the processes as shown below but still nothing.

```
var union = wpsClient.getProcess('local','gs:UnionFeatureCollection');
var catalogImport = wpsClient.getProcess('local','gs:Import');

//Start with the union
union.configure({
   inputs:{
       first:features1,
       second:features2
   }
});
catalogImport.execute({
   inputs:{
       features:union.output('result'),
       workspace:'workspace1',
       store:'analysis1',
       name:layerName,
       srs:new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326')
   },
    success:function(output){
        localStorage.setItem("LayerName",JSON.stringify(output));
        window.location.reload();
    }
})
```